# How can transfer data using Box cox?

Tags: r, lm

I have a data as below.

Data:

```
temperature stage Replicate week Nematode_Number

        T20   All         1    1            60.0
        T20   All         2    1            72.7 
        T20   All         3    1            69.3
        T20   All         4    1            45.3
        T20   All         5    1            40.7
```

I like to find linear model and then normalize data based on Box cox for this data but There is a error.

```
Script: 

> mode (all)
[1] "list"

> is.data.frame (all)
[1] TRUE

> getClass(class(all))
Class "data.frame" [package "methods"]

Slots:


Name:                .Data               names           row.names            .S3Class
Class:                list           character data.frameRowLabels           character

Extends: 
Class "list", from data part
Class "oldClass", directly
Class "vector", by class "list", distance 2

> a <- boxcox(lm(Nematode_Number ~ week, data = all))

Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 'data' argument is of the wrong type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(temperature=rep("T20",5),
                 stage=rep("All",5),
                 Replicate=1:5, week=rep(1,5),
                 Nematode_Number=c(60.0, 72.7, 69.3, 45.3, 40.7),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
```

**Is this what you want?**

This works

```
lm(Nematode_Number ~ week, data=df)
```

And this works

```
library(MASS)
boxcox(Nematode_Number ~ week, data=df)
```

And this works

```
temp <- lm(Nematode_Number ~ week, data=df)
boxcox(temp, data=df)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `boxcox` should work. Well boxcox also does take formula objects. So try to clear your environment if you can or `rm(all)` and reread it again. Then try the code below if at all this code doesn't work prior to the above.

```
 a=boxcox(Nematode_Number~week,data=all)
```

Hope this helps